# 3DES iOS encrypt different from .Net server

Tags: ios, encryption, 3des

I'm trying to encrypt a request, I made this function but I'm getting a different encrypt value in the .NET server. This is the function I'm using in iOS:

```
- (NSData *)Encrypt3DESWithInput:(NSString *)input
                         key:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *inputData = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSUInteger dataLength = [inputData length];

    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSize3DES;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          [keyData bytes],
                                          kCCKeySize3DES,
                                          initializationVector,
                                          [inputData bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

These are the values im using in the private key and the initialization vector:

```
static NSString *const privateKey = @"";
static const char initializationVector[8] = {31, 10, 35, 17, 0, 42, 151, 64};
```

Comment: Don't use a key shorter than the natural key length of the algorithm. The padding that is used may not be the same on two different implementations. Provide a sample key, iv, plain text and cryptText all in hex ascii (of decimal for the newbies.

Comment: Since there is no key and the way the key data is created there is just a =key pointed into random memory: the encrypted data is different every time. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a key that is the natural length of the encryption/decryption routine. Don't rely on key padding, that is undefined. If you have a password use `PBKDF2` to create a full length secure key..

The key string is `@""` yet the key data is created by `[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

```
NSString *keyString = @"";
NSData *keyData = [keyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

NSLog output:

> keyString: ''
>   keyData: <>

Note the key length is 0 so the DES method will access random data from memory.